# How to add span on WordPress Title for first and third word

Tags: customization, title

I need to know how to add a span to title post, not only for 1 word, but 2 or 3 words as I need.

For example I have a normal title like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consectetur adipiscing

I need to add span to be like this:

```
<span>Lorem</span> ipsum <span>dolor sitamet</span> consectetur adipiscing
```

I change this:

```
 the_title();
```

With this:

```
$words    = explode( ' ', the_title( '', '',  false ) );
$words[0] = '<span>' . $words[0] . '</span>';
$title    = implode( ' ', $words );
echo $title;
```

But only give span to the first word. Any idea to give span on any place as I need?

Comment: Why not add the `span` elements directly into the title in the WordPress admin panel? I'm 90% sure it accepts HTML.

Comment: Firstly, yes, WordPress handles HTML in post titles, but could lead to problems with encoding in e.g. widgets, had it all before. So far it seems the problem is probably better handled through Javascript, if it is for styling purposes only?

Comment: @howdy_McGee yes, it is, but that technique have problem for consistency for user.

Comment: @physalis  Yes for styling purpose. Do you have idea with JQuery? Really appreciate for help.

Comment: How do you decide which words get spans? Is it always going to be word 1, word 3 + 4?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee : yes, but basically it's can be 1,2 or else.

Comment: A client-side solution like jQuery would introduce a flash to the title in my opinion.  As the page loads, the title w/o span tags would be visible.  When the JS fires, the span styling would be present, causing a visible change in the title.

Comment: Yes, by Jquery I am afraid will affect to all title, I only need for some custom area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your provided code (as you state) is wrapping the first word of your title with the `<span>`tag, then the following should also wrap the third word.

```
$words    = explode( ' ', the_title( '', '',  false ) );
$words[0] = '<span>' . $words[0] . '</span>';
$words[2] = '<span>' . $words[2] . '</span>';
$title    = implode( ' ', $words );
echo $title;
```

The words in the `$words[]` array would correspond to the numeric index.  [0] being your first word, [1] being your second word, etc.

---

**Edit:** To wrap multiple words in your title there are multiple options.  Here is the simplest, which involves prefixing the first word in the chain and suffixing the last word in the chain.  In this example, we're wrapping the first, second and third word with a `<span>` tag.

```
$words    = explode( ' ', the_title( '', '',  false ) );
$words[0] = '<span>' . $words[0];
$words[2] = $words[2] . '</span>';
$title    = implode( ' ', $words );
echo $title;
```

To summarize, you are not wrapping each word with an open/close tag pair.  Simply open the tag in front of the first word to wrap, and close the tag after the last word.

Comment: While this is a solid answer - in the example OP gave in his question it looks like they're also adding `span`s either around 1 word or multiple words which will mess up `implode()`. How OP ascertains how many words to encapsulate in spans is beyond. Also note that OP is referring to `the_title()` for pages and posts and not `wp_title()`. All in all +1

Comment: @jdm2112  It is work to add span for first and third word. It's use the_title, not deprecated wp_title. Can be the solution but still try to give span for more 1 word. Thank you.

Comment: My mistake.  Working through multiple projects adding the new theme support for titles, therefore the `wp_title()` conflation! Will edit to remove deprecation notice.  @mailmulah I will add an option for wrapping multiple words.

Comment: @jdm2112 : ah, ya! Perfect solution for me. Thank you.